# bibtex techreport entry - authors from different institutions

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite this report:

http://www.aaafoundation.org/pdf/usRAPIIIFinalReport.pdf

It was written by two groups of authors from two institutions.  The report was sponsored by some other organizations. It was prepared for yet another organization. So now the question is: what should I fill in each field in a bibtex `@techreport` entry?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the BibTeX manual (`texdoc bibtex`)

> **institution** The sponsoring institution of a technical report.

Then, based on this "AAA foundation..." should be what you put in the `institution` field for the report at hand.

Comment: What if it is funded by more than one institution, or there is no specific source of funding for this report?